# I need to sync google drive with my xamarin forms application

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-drive-api

I need to connect google drive with my xamarin forms application.

I have tried this code==>https://xamarindev.blog/2017/03/22/google-drive-api-with-xamarin-forms/

I take a reference project from github through this link https://github.com/Dineshbala1/GoogleDriveAPI-XamarinForms

In the above link the code is related to "Shared Project" and I'm work with xamarin forms ".Net standard".

So please guide me, how could I apply google drive API in my xamarin forms project?

Ask me if anybody need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that Xamarin Components are no longer supported in Visual Studio, and should be replaced by NuGet packages. 
You can follow the instructions to manually remove component references from your projects from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/component-nuget?tabs=vswin).

For more info using Xamarin forms:

- [Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/)
- [Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.Android 1.2.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Google.Drive.Api.Android/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just need to inform you that My xamarin app is working properly and I had recently completed Gmail authentication functionality in my Xamarin app. Now I just want to integrate google drive with my xamarin app.